# iOS webview send var to javascript html file

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am loading an html file to uiWebView and getting variables that were set previously on a div using:

```
 NSString *body = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                          @"document.getElementById('var').innerHTML"];
```

but I need now the reverse process, set variable to html file using javascript. Html javascript code will wait then until I send a var. Something like following pseudo code,

```
 [self.webView stringSetJavaScriptFromString:
           @"document.setElementById('var').innerHTML", myStringVar];
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already tried

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('var').innerHTML = '%@';",myStringVar]];
```

?